# Zf2 form fieldset returns no fields

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have done bunch of projects using ZF2 and Doctrine2. I build my form with as it follows: Create Form class extending Form, then create Fieldsets and set it as a base fieldset, then in the fieldset I add my fields. Within module.php I create factories in formElementConfig for my forms. It was working allways this way until now. I created a new project and suddenly I encounter a problem which I cant find what is going on. This is my code

```
 //module.php
 public function getFormElementConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'OfferForm' => function($sm) {
                    $locator = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                    $form = new \Application\Form\OfferForm();
                    $form->setServiceLocator($locator);
                    return $form;
                },
            )
        );
    }

//Form
class OfferForm extends Form implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAttributes(array(
            'id' => 'offer',
            'method' => 'post',
            'class'  => 'custom',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ));

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post')
            ->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
            ->setInputFilter(new InputFilter());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'offer',
            'type' => 'Application\Form\Fieldset\OfferFieldset',
            'options' => array(
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
            'name' => 'csrf'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'submit',
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => $this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')->translate('Submit offer'),
                'class' => 'btn btn-info'
            )
        ));
    }
....

//Fieldset

class OfferFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
            ->setObject(new Offer());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text',
            'attributes' => array(
                'required' => 'required',
                'class' => 'form-control',
            )
        ));
        ....other fileds
    }
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
      ....
    }
}


//Controller

$em = $this->getObjectManager();
        $offer = new Offer();
        $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('FormElementManager')->get('OfferForm');
        $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em, 'Application\Entity\Offer'))->bind($offer);
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($this->request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                var_dump('ok');
            }
        }
        $form->prepare();
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form,
        ));
```

This way of doing things is allways working for me until now. If I try to get form element in the Veiw with $this->form->get('offer')->get('title') it says there is no field with name 'title'

One thing that i noticed is when form is called in the controller ($form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('FormElementManager')->get('OfferForm');) the fieldset method init() where all my fields are set is not invoked. 
I tried to dump data there and to die() the application but it did not get in to the method at all.

I can provide more code but I think this is all about building the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add your fieldset to the formelementmanager configuration. The manager's initializer will call your fieldset init() method.

Comment: Yes, that works. But I am really confused now because in my past projects I never used to define the fieldsets and the worked every time. Even nested fieldset. Very strange

Comment: Hey man, look what happens now.... 

When i call $this->formRow($form->get(....)->get(element)) the output is very strange. And it dosent get the right elements. I call ffor examle elemnt 'name' it outpusts element 'price'....

<input type="text" name="offer[offer[offer[offer[offer[offer[offer[offer[offer[offer[price]]]]]]]]]]" required="required" class="form-control" value="">

Comment: It actualy dosent work.... Something realy crazy is going on... If I have 2 element it get only the last element, show it twice and in element name it makes it offer[offer[element]]. If the elements are 3 it outputs 3 equal elements offer[offer[offer[lastelement]]]. But thats is not all. If I have 3 text elements and 2 select elements it makes 3 equal text fields and 2 equal selects. The last uniqe type is used. This is something that is realy realy crazy and strange.

Comment: How did you add the elements to the fieldsets in the past? Using the constructor or the init() method? About the strange naming, looks like some kind of recursion is going on. I don't see anything strange with your code yet. Your best bet would be to simplify your code until it works, step through the code with xdebug or compare this code to your other working forms.

Comment: I add them usung init(). This example that i gave you is the right example that works on every other project untill now. I have never encountered this kind of problem.

Comment: Create form with init(), create Fieldset with init(), define factories=>form.... and call the form with FormElementManager. This was a documentation of ZF2, and every time I make thinks like that. Just dont know what happened :(